# change directory with pipe in UNIX

Tags: unix, pipe

I am writing a C program that basically is supposed to change directory and call another program. I have tried :

```
system("cd ... | ./test.exe");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's `...`? Did you mean `..`?

Answer (score 2):

Surely, you wanna do:

```
cd /this/is/a/dir && ./command
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
system("cd ... ; ./test.exe");
```

(I'm assuming ... is a placeholder for your directory).

If that doesn't work, consider creating a short script (call it script.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ...
./test.exe
```

then execute

```
system("./script.sh");
```

Comment: If you do `system("cd ... ; ./test.exe");` and the directory does not exist, let's say for the sake of argument, it will still try to attempt to run `./test.exe`, and the script will fail also by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore the use of the `system` function, and answer as if the pipeline command was typed at the command line, for the sake of making this point:

When you create a pipeline like `cd somedir | ./test.exe`, the shell is allowed to run each command of the pipeline in a separate subshell environment.  Furthermore, there's no guarantee that they'll execute in strict left-to-right order.  So the cd command doesn't affect the environment of test.exe in the way you're expecting.  `cd`, being a shell builtin, can only affect the environment of the shell it's executed in, which in this case would be a subshell created as part of setting up the pipeline, not the shell into which the pipeline command was typed.

Comment: +1, You actually explained the functionality of the pipe. Very good, wish I was this good :) (And by the way I would accept this as the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

"cd" is not going to work with a pipe. Try something like:

`chdir("/path");

system("./test.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
system("cd .. && ./test.exe");
```